# Image/texture filters in PlayN (perhaps using opengl), how to approach?

Tags: opengl, playn, fragment-shader, convolution

I'm currently trying PlayN and the first testbed is up and running, so now I'm onto something more advanced: following a show-off example for [simulating liquids with AS3 and box2d](http://www.emanueleferonato.com/2012/05/16/simulating-mudslime-with-box2d-bitmaps-and-filters/), I've managed to get it all working except for the blurring. Fortunately PlayN comes along with a LWJGL-hook, so I thought to give it a shot but even though I know a few things in OpenGL, still my wisdom comes to a mere end. I have some basic ideas about how to do it in OpenGL and of course I know how to change colors and vertex-stuff in general - anyone up for a few hints regarding filters, convolution in particular? The problem is that PlayN doesn't really offer a fast API to its internal image-representation ... other than OpenGL.

I have my "game" all set up... there are several layers; one of them, the "dynamic layers" is constantly being fed with little image-textured dots (just a tiny gif) that map to physical body. they all fall down, disappear and are being destroyed properly. What I now need is some rather performant means to set a blur-filter on this dynamic layer.

Does anyone have any experience with OpenGL-shaders and can provide me with anything to start with?

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your code, i m not sure if i can answer your question, but the shader subsystem isn't really very well exposed as an api, but its not impossible to hook into. If you look at this page, it might give you some hints as to how to attach a shader to your layer : https://github.com/dmg46664/playn/wiki/GLShader